# wpf calendar control not displaying properly

Tags: wpf, xaml

My display of the calendar control has two problems as shown below.  The date is not placed in the header and is truncated.  The image was generated from a window that has NOTHING on it except the control itself.  If I put it on a canvas or grid or stackpanel, I get the same problems.

[image]

What can I do to fix the problem.  Net framework 4.6.1

Edit:  Here is the ALL of the XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="theClass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PIM"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="theName"
    Title="theTitle"
    Height="600"
    Width="600"
    Background="#FFE8FFFD"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Calendar />
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you done anything to customize it? If so we'll need to see some code dude.

Comment: No customization.  I added the calendar to the window by entering this XAML:  <Calendar />  .There is NO code behind.  What you see is the entirety of the whole window.  There is nothing else to see

Comment: I ask about the possibility of customization because your screenshot looks "off" in that the header doesn't display in the gray header area. I would also expect the header area to stretch the full width and display in `Month, Year` format including the comma which I don't see. Either way in my opinion this would be a tough one to troubleshoot from just a screenshot either way, sorry.

Comment: Yes, Chris, the "off" parts are exactly the problem I'm trying to fix.  See the full XAML in my revised opening.  Maybe I have to reload .NET??

Comment: If you right click the calendar control and go to -> Edit Template, does it give the option to "Edit Current" or just the bottom two of "Edit a copy" and "Create Empty"? If you're able to "Edit Current" then I would assume someones got a custom template somewhere that would be your culprit. Because at first glance, that template has been messed with.

Comment: "Edit Current" is disabled.  The bottom two are enabled.

Comment: Well shoot, I completely expected there to be some funky template somewhere causing your issue. You can google images of default wpf calendar controls to see what would be the expected layout. So at this point personally I'm a bit stumped. I suppose you could make a copy and go fix those issues, but you really shouldn't have too. Maybe someone will come along with more insight but I'd have to be in front of it to troubleshoot from here. Sorry amigo, I honestly figured it would be a super simple one.